# Can 12.04 be installed using Btrfs only?

Tags: 12.04, btrfs

In the past it was not possible to install Ubuntu on a pure Btrfs file system (/ btrfs + swap), will it be possible for 12.04?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have been able to install Ubuntu into btrfs since 10.10

See the following guides

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/btrfs

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1389279

With that said, see the stability section on the wiki

You can boot a btrfs root (/boot) partition with grub2 (1.99), but the initrd has to be compressed with zlib (not lzo)

Looking as /etc/initramfs-tools/initramfs.conf, gzip appears to be the default, you should be good to go.

And from the ubuntu wiki page I gave you :

> As of 11.04-beta1, it is possible to use only btrfs file systems with the caveat that grub _MUST_NOT_ be installed to the boot sector of the btrfs volume containing /boot.

So install Ubuntu 11.04 or higher, be sure to install grub to the MBR (this is the default behavior of the installer).

Comment: Yes but only when using a ext4 /boot partition. I have no problems with btrfs - just a question.

Comment: @Paradiesstaub I thought that Natty fixed that (though I could be wrong - I'm still an EXT4 user)

Comment: I tried it. Its possible to install Ubuntu 12.04 on '/' btrfs and swap only.